# Express server static ejs file with css and js does not work

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, static-files

I am trying to make a website with node js , and I have /home and /contact. Every thing works until I put css and js at both of them and the second call does not work.I am reffering that I acces first the /home (everything works), then I do /contact and the page remains the same.

```
const PORT = 7777;

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/home',(req,res)=> {
    console.log("get /home");
    app.use(require("express").static('./views/Home'));
    res.render('Home/home.ejs');
});

app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("get /contact");
    app.use(require("express").static('./views/Contact'));
    res.render('Contact/contatct.ejs');
});

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`it's alive on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
)
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do **not** require `express` multiple times. **Do** require `express` **once** at the top of your module
- Do **not** add middleware in response to a request for a specific page. **Do** add it when the application loads.
- Do **not** mix your view templates with your static files

```js
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/home',(req,res)=> {
    console.log("get /home");
    res.render('Home/home.ejs');
});

app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("get /contact");
    res.render('Contact/contatct.ejs');
});

app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
```

Then in your EJS templates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/file_name_in_static_folder.css">
```

Or

```
<img src="/static/image_used_in_one_template_but_stored_in_static_folder.png">
```

Comment: And If I have multiple folders and I want to acces not just the Views folder ?

Comment: You can call `app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));` multiple times with different paths. Just don't do it in the middle of an endpoint function.